# What is going on with these Mars questions with female astronauts?

Tags: discussion, support

In past about 5 days I have seen almost 6 to 7 **Female on Mars** questions. Which feels like a lot of repeatation.

How do we prevent or deal with these kind of questions?

Comment: Some users have near-obsessive focuses on certain topics. Although this is a particularly extreme case. The normal voting and moderation methods usually work.

Comment: Its happening on the worldbuilding.SE as well. been 3 that i've seen at least, maybe more

Comment: I know, right? Everyone knows [Men are From Mars and Women are from Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Are_from_Mars,_Women_Are_from_Venus).

Comment: @Machavity, i am literally laughing. :D

Comment: Might it have had something to do with an episode of National Geographic's Mars series?

Comment: ^ Season 2 episode 1 November 12, 2018 episode 2 November 19, 2018

Answer (score 2):

We can only guess.

- Someone with an agenda about the usual male words used
- Someone writing a novel/story

Since we don't **know**, ignore (as Organic Marble commented).

Some of these questions are/were duplicates, then vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

I think I noticed that one of these posts was by a female. Her story was about female space explorers. There may be a feminist agenda but I don't really think it matters.

A question about, e.g.  "what would a woman in a skirt and jumper experience in a vacuum" can just be answered generically. For example, "A human wearing only casual Earth-type clothes would inevitably die after X minutes because ..."

Of course mere repetition of the same question is subject to the usual rules.